# Stroke Selection won't use selected color

Tags: gimp

I'm having this problem where stroke selection won't use selected color. So I'd select an area and go to Edit -> Stroke Selection then Gimp would automatically change my selected color to another color. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I only had this problem whilst trying to work on a GIF because it was using an indexed colour palette, once I changed the colour palette to RGB it worked fine.

Comment: How about re-opening this question and moving it to the right SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user977151, use the option "Stroke with a paint tool", and if you wish, check the option "Emulate brush dynamics". It'll use your tool sets.

Comment: @user977151 : It happened to me too: I was under the impression the color was wrong, but it was just the blue line of the path that made me believe this. Either enlarge the scale to see better, or delete the path after having stroked it, and the actual stroke color will be apparent.

Answer (score 17):

Finally figured it out!  You need to change the color AFTER you open the Stroke Path (or Stroke Selection) dialog box.  Whew! I was going crazy with this problem.  I have no idea why so few people are encountering this bug.

Comment: That worked, but "smells" like a bug.

Comment: This didn't work for me. What did get around the bug was to use the foreground color in another function, "Edit->Fill with FG Color," undo that, then do the stroke.